# How to place checkbox in each and every row in a dynamically generated table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I am generating a table dynamically based on the columns selected by the user. I am able to do it. This is my code:

```
<?php


if (($getdata)||(mysql_errno == 0))  
{  
  echo "<table width='100%' >
  <thead><tr>";  
  if (mysql_num_rows($getdata)>0)  
  {  

          $i = 0;  
          while ($i < mysql_num_fields($getdata))  
          {  

       echo "<th align='center'>". mysql_field_name($getdata, $i) . "</th>";

       $i++;  
    }  
    echo "</tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";


    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getdata,MYSQL_ASSOC))  
    {  
      echo "<tr >";  
      foreach ($rows as $data)  
      {  
        echo "<td align='center' width='auto'>". $data . "</td>";  
      }  
    }  
  }else{  
    echo "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'></td></tr></tr>";  
  }  
  echo "</tbody></table>";  
}else{  
  echo "Error in running query :". mysql_error();  
}  

  ?>
```

Now I need to place check box in the each row including `<thead>` and I have to make first column as hyper link in each row. I tried these but not successful.

```
echo "<th style="width:8px;">"."<input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_2 .checkboxes" />"."</th>"
```

For hyperlink i tried this

```
echo "<td align='center' width='auto'><a>". $rows['Asset Id'] . "</a></td>";
```

For this I am getting hyperlink for all columns. I need to get hyperlink for only one first column of the table.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You either need to escape the double quotes like this: `"style=\"width:8px\""` or use single quotes inside double quotes as you did before. Like that: `"style='width:8px'"`

Comment: Syntax error in `echo "<th style="width:8px;">"."<input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_2 .checkboxes" />"."</th>"`

Comment: I got check boxes. I am not able to get hyperlinks. I need hyperlink in the first column of the table which is dynamically generated.

Comment: hyperlink to where? Your attempt just has an `<a></a>`